# Cannot process AWS tagging

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, aws-cloudformation

I'm new to AWS and I have a task to add tags to different resources.
I'm getting this error on the CloudFormation

`Did not have IAM permissions to process tags on AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline resource.`

Is anyone familiar with this? I just added `Tags` in Properties.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error says it all. Check the IAM permissions of the cloudformation role that they can assign tags to the [codepipeline resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/permissions-reference.html). If you are using specific permissions you will need to enable [TagResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_TagResource.html), otherwise if the role has permissions:

```
"codepipeline":"*"
```

Ensure that they are able to apply them to the resource in question.

Comment: hi thanks for this! https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html i saw this doc. What's the difference with adding this `tag:TagResources` instead of `codepipeline:TagResource` in actions? Sorry. Really new to this.

Comment: No worries, the document you linked is in reference to the AWS SDK api integration not Cloudformation. Whereas **codepipeline:TagResource** is a policy you would include on a IAM role attached to your Cloudformation deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Your Cloudformation is probably correct, but the IAM User or Role doesn't have the IAM permissions for [`codepipeline:TagResource`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_TagResource.html)

Checkout the [available IAM actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awscodepipeline.html) for Codepipeline and ensure your IAM user/role has these permissions

Comment: hi thanks for this! https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html i saw this doc. What's the difference with adding this `tag:TagResources` instead of `codepipeline:TagResource` in actions? Sorry. Really new to this.